# How can I change the actual value of a list/variable outside of a function inside a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I add something to a list outside of a function:

```
greeting = ["Hello","Hi"]
def addGreeting():
    greeting.append(raw_input("add greeting here: "))
```

How can I change the actual value of a list/variable outside of a function inside a function?

Comment: You can either pass it to the function or declare a global variable

Comment: What's wrong with this? [no-repro](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P70oNbUkMy9dwVYhWskjNScnX0lHySNTKZYrJTVNITElxR2qQEPTiksBCGAa9BILClLzUjSKEsvjM/MKSks0lICq4dIKGalFqVYKSpqaXCiGcBUUZeaVaMCUaf7/n5EJAA)??? Also, just do `global greeting` at the start of your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the code you posted works as intended:

```
greeting = ["Hello","Hi"]

print(greeting)

def addGreeting():
    greeting.append(raw_input("add greeting here: "))

addGreeting()
print(greeting)
```

Whatever you added will indeed be in `greeting`. But this is very messy and implicit, and it relies on the specific names you've given variables. Instead, consider doing

```
def add_greeting_from_input(greetings):
    greetings.append(raw_input("add greeting here: "))
    return greetings
```

Now this function is much more flexible and is totally unambiguous about what it acts on. Functions that have implicit behavior should ideally be confined to classes, where they obviously (hopefully) act on the instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
greeting = ["Hello", "Hi"]
```

Design a function that takes in parameters to replace with arguments when run.

```
def addGreeting(list,newgreeting):
    list.append(newgreeting)
```

Now call the function

```
addGreeting(greeting,"This is a new greeting!")
```